# How do I convert a nullable int to a string that will be safe for computers in different locales?

Tags: c#, int, type-conversion, locale, nullable

I'm converting a `nullable integer` to a `string`, and Resharper warns me to use InvariantCulture.

```
shipment.ShipmentID.ToString()
```

A quick **Alt-Enter, Enter** later, gives me this:

```
shipment.ShipmentID.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

Unfortunately, Resharper isn't satisfied, and suggests the same thing, which doesn't make sense to me.

```
shipment.ShipmentID.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, 
                                CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

ToString() on the nullable int won't build, giving me an error stating **No overload method 'ToString' takes 1 arguments**.

Non-nullable ints behave differently.

```
int requiredInt = 3;
// no Resharper or compiler warning
var stringFromRequiredInt = requiredInt.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

What should I do to convert a `nullable int` to a `string` that will be safe for computers in different locales?

Comment: What happens when you use shipment.ShipmentID.Value? With nullable types, I usually check for null using the .HasValue boolean and then use the .Value.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`Nullable<T>` doesn't have a `ToString()` overload with arguments; ReSharper isn't quite handling the situation properly.

Since `default(Nullable<int>).ToString()` returns `string.Empty`, you can make ReSharper happy like this:

```
shipment.ShipmentID.HasValue 
        ? shipment.ShipmentID.Value.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) : ""
```

Alternatively:

```
shipment.ShipmentID != null 
        ? ((int)shipment.ShipmentID).ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) : ""
```

Answer (score 1):

Check this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4c5zdc6a%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).

> you should use the invariant culture only for processes that require culture-independent results, such as system services. In other cases, it produces results that might be linguistically incorrect or culturally inappropriate.

**UPDATE:** So one of the main purposes to use it might be e.g. 'if' statement comparison.